# strange value of total sum of select in typescript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

In my angular project I've to calculate the sum of the scoring selections. I don't know why the `totalScore` gives me strange results. `totalScore` is the sum of `city.score` values.

In DB i have this situation:

```
STATE
--------------
id | name     |
--------------
 1 | USA      |
--------------
 2 | UK       |
--------------
 3 | Italy    |
--------------

CITY
-----------------------------------
id | name       | score | state_id |
-----------------------------------
1  | New York   | 8     | 1        |
-----------------------------------
2  | Boston     | 6     | 1        |
-----------------------------------
3  | Miami      | 4     | 1        |
-----------------------------------
4  | London     | 9     | 2        |
-----------------------------------
5  | Manchester | 8     | 2        |
-----------------------------------
6  | Liverpool  | 9     | 2        |
-----------------------------------
7  | Rome       | 11    | 3        |
-----------------------------------
8  | Florence   | 10    | 3        |
-----------------------------------
9  | Turin      | 7     | 3        |
-----------------------------------
```

In `summary.component.ts`:

```
  state: State[]
  city: City[]
  selection: number[]
  msg1: boolean = false
  totalScore: number

  constructor(
    private service: ScoreSummaryService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getState().subscribe(data => {
      this.state = data;
    })
    this.service.getCity().subscribe(data => {
      this.city = data;
    })
  }

  totalOutput() {
    const total = this.city.filter(c => this.selection.includes(c.id)).reduce((a,c) => a + c.score, 0)
    this.totalScore = total
    this.msg1 = true
  }
```

In `summary.component.html`:

```html
<div name="selt" *ngFor="let array of state; index as j">
            <strong>• {{ array.state }}</strong>
            <select name="sel" [(ngModel)]="selection" style="margin-top: 10px;" class="form-control">
              <ng-container *ngFor="let array2 of city; index as i">
                <option *ngIf="array2.stateId.id === array.id" [value]="array2.id">
                  {{ array2.name }} <p>|</p>
                  {{ array2.score }}
                </option>            
              </ng-container>
            </select>
            <label></label>
          </div>
          
          <button type="submit" (click)="totalOutput()"
          class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
          <hr>
          <div class="row" *ngIf="msg1">          
            <p>Score: <strong>{{totalScore}}</strong></p> 
          </div>
```

- **state.ts**

```
export class State {
    id: number
    name: string
}
```

- **city.ts**

```
import { State } from "./state"

export class City {
    id: number
    name: string
    score: number
    stateId: State
}
```

Comment: Not getting your purpose. So, if you select `Miami` from `USA`, what will be the total score?

Comment: And also add the `State` and `City` class or interface skeleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your requirement is unclear I've implemented a solution at [StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aws445?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

See if this works for you.

**Edit:** (Check updated link)

Add these lines in your ngOnInit():

```
this.state.forEach(f =>
  this.selection.push(this.city.filter(c => c.stateId.id === f.id)[0].id)
);
```

Comment: thank you, it work. Is it possible that each option of the select has the values already entered when the page is opened? (ngOnInit) That is, by default there is always the first option already selected and therefore you can make the total

Comment: Done. You can check.

Comment: I have this error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at summary.component.ts:34, that is `this.city.filter(c => c.stateId.id === f.id)[0].id`. I had to put `stateId.id`, otherwise the function would always give me `false` value

Comment: If you host your project or at least share the `State` and `City`'s structure, I'll be able to help properly.

Comment: Updated. Sorry to say, your variable naming is weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230263/discussion-between-daniele-vallorani-and-zunayed-shahriar).